# MATLAB: Save image file names to vector

Tags: matlab

I'm doing some sequential image processing and I'm trying to pull out data from each image into a csv file for use in Excel.

I was trying to do this just using a vector for each image variable along with the filename.

However, I'm having trouble making a vector with the filenames within the processing loop. Here's my code.

```
ImageFolder = C:\Users\X\Documents\MATLAB\Research\Temp
filePattern = fullfile(ImageFolder, "*.tif');
tifFiles = dir(filePattern);

for k = 1:length(tifFiles) % Open sequence loop
 baseFileName = tifFiles(k).name;
 fullFileName = fullfile(ImageFolder, baseFileName);
 fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', baseFileName);
 close all % Close images from previous cycle

% skip some lines

Count(k) = size(Areas,1)  <- Works
Porosity(k) = (sum(Areas) / (size(Istretch,1)*size(Istretch,2)))*100 
Size(k) = sum(Areas)/Number 
ImageName(k) = baseFileName  <- This is wrong
```

That just prints out 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. letter of each filename as you go through the sequence. I assume there's some simple solution here but I'm not thinking of it. Can anybody clear this up for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab a file name or any other "string" is a vector of chars and not a scalar, so you can't assign it to a single element of a vector. Use a [cell](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) instead: `ImageName{k} = baseFileName`